# "spin" recvfrom socket - good idea if latency is a requirement?

Tags: c++, sockets

I receive datagrams from UDP Mulitcast socket like that:

```
int res=recvfrom(socketId,buf,sizeof(char) * RECEIVE_BUFFER_SIZE,0, (SOCKADDR *)& Sender, &SenderAddrSize);
```

According to MSDN this call blocks until datagram is available:

---

If no incoming data is available at the socket, the recvfrom function blocks and waits for data to arrive according to the blocking rules defined for WSARecv with the MSG_PARTIAL flag not set unless the socket is nonblocking.

---

Now in the same thread I want to receive packets from another socket too. So now I want to listen TWO sockets in ONE thread and data from both of them should be processed ASAP. Because of that i can not use blocking `recvfrom` anymore, I should use something like that (pseude-code):

```
while (true) {
    non blocking recvfrom call to Socket1
    if new datagram available in Socket1 then process
    non blocking recvfrom call to Socket2
    if new datagram available in Socket2 then process
}
```

I would say that I "spin" sockets. I understand that "spinning" spents CPU a lot but this is OK as my primary requirement is **latency**.

I don't want to process two sockets in two different threads because data from these sockets is the same and "merging" this data from two threads is a little bit complicated - it would be much easier to "arbitrate" data from two sockets in one thread. I have to listen both sockets as UDP is unreliable and i need to statistically decrease the probability of packet loss.

I have following question:

- taking into account that I agree to spent CPU for better latency is it a good idea to "spin socket"?
- how much microseconds can I win "spinning" socket instead of calling regular blocking receive? (well will I win something or it's just CPU power wasting?)

Comment: Are you using Windows 8/2012? It added a new API specifically for low-latency sockets: [Registered I/O](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh437193.aspx)

Comment: If you can't use 2 different threads because of data reconciliation problems then just use 3 threads: one to receive from each socket, and push the packets to a message queue that the third thread will process. Spinning (and thus burning the CPU) is rarely a good option except in those cases where you can **prove** the spin will stop in a short, limited time frame (which is not your case).

Comment: @CoryNelson I'm using Windows 8 for development and Server 2008 R2 for production. And I prefer something portable as I going to migrate to Linux. But it's interesting anyway, cause I'm not sure how long I will stay with 2008 R2 in production and probably I can try to upgrade to 2012...

Comment: @syam things are complicated :) having two threads or three will add some extra memory usage (because i need to store duplicate data in each thread), extra copies and probably inter-thread communication. It would be much easier to implement everything in one thread, and I have 12 (24 with HT) cores on my machine so I can spent one core to make things simpler and faster. and I don't need to try to save CPU power as entire server is used only to run this program.

Comment: Try select() to wait on both sockets.

Comment: @brianbeuning if `select()` has the same performance as `epoll`?

Comment: @javapowered: The only difference my proposed model will do is the thread-safe message queue (which can even be lock-free). Both "network" threads don't need to maintain state, they are just here to block on the UDP sockets and then pass the packet to the third thread. Only that third thread needs your data structures.

Comment: @syam and with your model you will process data TWICE. remember both sockets has the same data.

Comment: `select()` is the way to go, as Brian suggests and it's also mostly portable between WinSock and POSIX. There is also a WinSock function that allows attaching events to socket activity, but these are not portable to Linux. There, you could perhaps use `poll()` or some other POSIX or Linux API though. If you need performance and portability, consider making the split at a higher abstraction level though and use platform-specific low-level APIs.

Comment: @doomster am I correct that I should "spin" non blocking version of "select"? because using something that "blocks" on Windows is by definition is not fast.

Comment: @javapowered select() blocks until some data is present to read. Equate block with not wasting CPU time and not slow.

Comment: Yep, I don't know where this claim that "blocking = not fast" is coming from either.

Comment: @brianbeuning i'm afraid if it blocks it diffenetely slow. i think i will loose just in this step 5 microseconds or so.

Comment: The obvious thing to do is implement it both ways (with blocking-in-select, and then with spinning) and measure it and see what performance you get.  Personally I'm pretty sure the block-in-select method will perform better, but I could be wrong -- you never know until you actually try it.

Comment: If you have severe restrictions on response times, maybe an OS or a non-realtime OS is not the right choice for you. If you don't, and you can live with the OS stalling your process for maybe a half second or so, blocking calls will make sure you don't swamp your CPU with answering "Are we there?" "Are we there now?" "And now?" "Now?" "Are you sure we're not there yet?" "And are we there now?" questions. BTW: By definition of `sizeof`, `char` has size 1, everything else is multiples thereof.

Comment: @doomster Linux is the best choice for HFT trading but i'm using Windows so far. realtime OS is not mandatory. "half a second"? are you kidding? i'm talking about microseconds, i don't want to spent extra 5 microseconds for blocking. and it's common tactic to use "spin" in HFT application, I already have one in my program. it seems so far under windows I have to use blocking or non-blocking `select` and when I will port to Linux I can use `epoll`.

Comment: I'm not kidding about the half second. What if the OS needs to read some data from hard disk, service a few interrupts etc? I'm not talking about average latencies but worst cases! A handful of scheduler timeslices should be something you must be prepared to deal with.